# Binding a Combobox's Itemsource to a method

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a form where I have a lot of Comboboxes and I wish to provide template data for the users to have access to or be able to enter their own.

My template data is stored in a Table with a Type key and values.

I wish to have a single method in my ViewModel that accepts a Key and returns a list that the Combo box uses like below.

```
public List<string> GetComboBoxList(string type)
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
            "Test1" + type,
            "Test2" + type
        };
    }
```

I have created an object data provider on my form:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetComboBoxList">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <system:String>Something</system:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

and have tried binding it like so:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1063,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" Height="96" ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataFromEnum}"/>
```

but I am getting the following exception on the controller:

> Exception: An object of the type "System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Collections.IEnumerable".

I don't know how to pass a new parameter or choose which parameter to use. Is what I am doing possible?  Or should I have a property for each combobox's template data?

Comment: Does `ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataFromEnum.Data}"` work?

Comment: BTW using ComboBoxItem as a data item class in your view model is not a great idea. You should return `List<String>` from `GetComboBoxList()`, instead of to ram ComboBoxItems into it via the ItemsSource property, which is not meant for that at all.

Comment: @EdPlunkett When I use dataFromEnum.Data I just get: The Resource dataFromEnum cannot be found.

Comment: Ohhh, right, duh -- my bad, you can't use a path in a StaticResource. Hang on a minute...

Comment: Have you tried ItemsSource="{Binding Source="{StaticResource dataFromEnum}" }"

Comment: @AliJey I just tried that and the error goes away, but it doesn't work, I just get a blank drop down.  I have updated the code above for my method and objectdatasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make much sense out of `ObjectDataProvider`. `MethodName` specifies a method, but *on what instance of what class* is it called? [MSDN doesn't say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodname(v=vs.110).aspx) (caveat: MSDN's WPF documentation appears to be a deliberate joke). You might be able to get somewhere by creating a `DataSourceProvider` and [assigning it to `ObjectInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.objectinstance(v=vs.110).aspx), but once you get into that "create a class to create a class to create a class" nonsense you're wasting the best years of your life chasing somebody else's bad design decisions all over the landscape.

At any rate, I can't find any way to make it hit a breakpoint in `GetComboBoxList()`, and I'm not getting any younger. So...

As you say, the normal way to do this is to have a property for each list in your viewmodel.

But if you've got too many lists for that to be convenient, or if you want to generate lists completely dynamically based on a parameter, there's more than one way to sneak a parameter from XAML back into some C# code.

Value converters are a sort of Swiss Army Knife in WPF, and you can do this with one quite easily.

```
public class ListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var vm = value as MyViewModelType;
        var type = (String)parameter;

        return new List<String>
        {
            "Test1" + type,
            "Test2" + type
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

View model:

```
//  Nothing!
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListConverter
        x:Key="listConverter"
        />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... snip ... -->

<ComboBox
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource listConverter}, ConverterParameter=Foo}"
    />
```

Notice we don't give the Binding a Path. The effect of that will be that the value passed into `ListConverter.Convert` for its `value` parameter will be your viewmodel (or whatever the `ComboBox`'s `DataContext` is, but that should really be the viewmodel). So if you want to grab something from your viewmodel to use in creating lists, just cast it and use it. If not, ignore it.

Comment: Alright, that worked.  But just one more question.  I was kind of hoping I could pass along the ListType on the control itself.  With this method, I'll have to have a property for each type correct?

Comment: Great! (blah blah more characters)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but the original data provider can work, you just need to change the binding statement from

```
ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataFromEnum}"
```

to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"
```